# Lock access to Android Settings but Wi-Fi

Tags: android

For my usecase i need to block access to phone settings for regular users, but they have to be able to see a list of available Wi-Fi and connect to them. 
I can use some of the lock apps in the market, but they lock the whole Setting app, including Wifi section.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Download "Leo Privacy gard" Android application That You Find In Android Play store You install  This Application and Lock Any applications and settings.

Comment: it blocks access to all settings =(

Comment: If You want to Block any application Go to setting Of application and choose who is lock

Comment: Wifi settings is a part of Settings application. I cant block the whole app!

Comment: Advanced Wifi Lock (Free). You try This Application One Time . I hope It is full fill Your requirement

Comment: Your Requirement is full fill or Not Please Give me response , I waiting for Your Response.         Your Response is more valuable foe me.

Comment: Yeah, thx, its works but its much better to write your own Wifi namager app. But your suggection works. + to karma

Comment: OK Another Time I Give You Better suggestions .Bye